# Modal Apache htaccess?

Tags: apache, authentication, modal-dialog, window

Apache realm auth is great for quick and dirty site acl's.  Can one do realm authentication with a modal window instead of the usual ugly native one? I know there are other solutions, like CAS, etc.  But Apache is always there (for the most part) and .htaccess is simple quick and easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: no.

This "ugly native window" is the kind of dialog your web browser shows when it encounters [HTTP authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) as defined in [RFC 2617](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt). This has nothing to do with Apache httpd, the dialog will look the same in your web browser, no matter which web server (Apache httpd, nginx, lighttpd, IIS, Hiawatha, fnord, gatling, …) generated the `WWW-Authenticate` header.

Answer (score 4):

As a short answer no; the ugly native window is not something coming from Apache, but from your browser.

When you ask access to a resource, basically answers with a response with status 401 (Unauthorized); the browser shows the usual modal dialog, asking for username and password; once you provide them, the browser tries again adding an Authentication: header with the username/password provided. If you can be authorized, fine, otherwise you've another 401, and the browser asks for the password again.